# D3.js array of objects not creating elements

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have an array of objects like so:

```
var dataObj = [{stuff:"thing"}, {other:"something"}, {you:"get"}, {the:"idea"}];
```

And I'm attempting to append one div with the key in it as text per object:

```
myElement
 .selectAll("div.myClass")
 .data([dataObj])
 .enter()
 .append("div")
 .attr('class', 'myClass')
 .text(function(d, i) { 
    return Object.keys(d)[i];
});
```

But this creates only one `div` element inside `myElement` like so:

```
<div id='myElement'><div class='myClass'>stuff</div></div>
```

What am I missing?

I also tried

```
myElement
 .selectAll("div.myClass")
 .data(dataObj)
 .enter()
 .append("div")
 .attr('class', 'myClass')
 .text(function(d, i) {
    console.log("This never shows"); 
    return Object.keys(d)[0];
});
```

to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dataObj is already an array. So it looks like you don't need to put in array

```
myElement
.selectAll("div.myClass")
.data(dataObj)
.enter()
.append("div")
.attr('class', 'myClass')
.text(function(d, i) { 
 return Object.keys(d)[i];
});
```

Comment: I had tried that originally, text callback never even gets called. See updated OP.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/freer4/3wqey0kg/ Yeah made my own lol it does work. But not working in my live code... maybe I missed something.

Comment: Oh in my live code the values aren't an array of objects, just one big object of key-value pairs.